# Android Studio emulator not working/ HAXM not installed

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

The silent install is passing but the regular haxm installation is not passing. When I go to run the emulator, I get the "Haxm is required to run this AVD - Unknown error". I have no idea what else I can do. I am currently using a Mac with Sierra. I have pretty tried what all the other stack overflow solutions say but nothing is working. 

 https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMBeL.png

Things I've tried: 
- uninstalling and re-installing android studio 
- running the silent instal

Comment: I have tried everything on that thread, and it did not work. Plus I am having a different issue. I have downloaded the HAXM packages but I can't get them to install

Comment: I am using a Mac, as I said in the question

Answer (score 1):

In Android studio go to: Preferences -> Appearances & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK then choose the SDK Tools tab and choose to download "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)" and click apply

[image]

To verify that Intel HAXM is running, open a terminal window and execute the following command:

```
kextstat | grep intel
```

If Intel HAXM is operating correctly, the command will show a status

message indicating that the kernel extension named

> "com.intel.kext.intelhaxm" is loaded.

**To stop or start Intel HAXM, use the following commands**:

Stop:

```
sudo kextunload –b com.intel.kext.intelhaxm
```

Start:

```
sudo kextload –b com.intel.kext.intelhaxm
```

Comment: I've already done all this. I then went to /Users/arnimj/Library/Android/sdk/extras/intel/Hardware../HAXM installation and ran that but thats where I am getting the problem

Comment: @user4151797 -  try then to install the standalone version. todo so go to intel's page at this link: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-mac-os-x

Comment: @user4151797 I added few cmd command to let you check if the process is up or not. hope it will work for you.

Comment: When I run the first command, i get "cant create -b" and "cant create com.intel.kext.intelhaxm". I will try to install the standalone version then

Comment: The standalone version gave me the same issues

Comment: @user4151797 do you meet the requirements? 
Mac OS X* 10.10 (Yosemite) or higher, up to macOS* 10.12 (Sierra)? what kind of processor do you have? maybe this is the issue..